# How can I add multiple data to a geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I wanna add multiple values to geom_bar. I'm getting these values from a csv file and adding it to dataset and from there I wanna add it to the plot. This is my code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

Passed_Students<- read.csv("C:/Users/kemal/Documents/OOP_eindopdracht/Eindopdracht_3/Processed_csv_file/Behaalde_studenten.csv")
Fast_students<- read.csv("C:/Users/kemal/Documents/OOP_eindopdracht/Eindopdracht_3/Processed_csv_file/Snelle_studenten.csv")
#rm(Behaalde_studenten)
#rm(Snelle_studenten)
#print(Behaalde_studenten)

ggplot(Passed_Students, aes(x="Passed_Students", y="Aantal")) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3) +
```

I want it so that `Passed_Students` and `Fast_student` are next to each other in the geom_bar. my Passed_student and fast_student looks like this:

```
  X1
1|23
2|34
3|36
4|72
5|100
```

they both look something like this only difference is that one is smaller then the other!

[It should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJiuj.png)

Comment: You do not need to load `tidyverse` if all you need is `ggplot2`. Please also add data with `dput(head(df, n))` Run this and add what it outputs to the question.

Comment: Greetings! Please share a reproducible dataset as shown here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

How I created the data:
using `tribble` function from `tibble` package (it is in tidyverse):

```
  
df <- tribble(
  ~N, ~Students,
  23, "Passed",
  34, "Fast",
  36, "Passed",
  72, "Fast",
  100, "Passed"
)
```

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Students, y=N, fill=Students))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.3)
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(N = c(23, 34, 36, 72, 100), Students = c("Passed", 
"Fast", "Passed", "Fast", "Passed")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: But ur adding these values by hand now right? and if so I need to get the data from my fast and pasted students and not hardcoded. So I need something like this df <- structure(list(N = c(Passed_students,Fast_Students), Students = c("Passed","Fast")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
#rm(Behaalde_studenten)

Comment: I already put data at the bottom. This is a `dput`. I will show you how I created the data in my update.